# Why is this constraint trigger not detecting invalid data at insert time, even though the logic it's evaluating works when in isolated SQL statement?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, constraints

NOTE: I solved this problem before I posted it to stackoverflow, I'm just posting the question and its answer here in case it helps anyone else who, like me, mistakenly thought that their trigger just wasn't firing when in fact it was just not seeing the right set of data due to incorrectly being marked as `STABLE` instead of `VOLATILE`.

I need to enforce a data integrity check on a table that is too complicated for a unique, check, or exclusion constraint, so I'm using a constraint trigger. The actual business logic this constraint is supposed to enforce is quite complicated, so I've created a minimal, digestible example that runs into the same issues as the actual constraint I'm trying to debug - namely, the trigger fails to stop me from INSERTing data that violates the constraint, even though the logic works when I test it in isolation.

In this minimal reproducible example, I have a data table, `debugging.my_data` which just holds an integer ID field, and two integer values that represent the lower and upper boundaries of some range. This is just a demonstration to show the issue I'm actually running into, so this data doesn't have any real-world meaning beyond that. The constraint I want to enforce is that no two rows in `debugging.my_data` can have value ranges that overlap with one another. So, if range #1 has values `[1, 10]` then range #2 can have `[20, 25]` but it can't have `[5, 12]` or `[10, 11]` because those values overlap with the range `[1, 10]`.

With that background info out of the way, here are the definitions of the minimal objects that I'm using to replicate the issue:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS debugging.my_data
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    range_min integer NOT NULL,
    range_max integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- The trigger function to be used with the actual constraint trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION debugging.make_sure_ranges_not_overlapping()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    STABLE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    found_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT id
        INTO found_id
    FROM debugging.my_data
    WHERE int4range(NEW.range_min, NEW.range_max, '[]') && int4range(range_min, range_max, '[]');
    IF FOUND THEN 
        RAISE 'Cannot insert range - it overlaps with range %',
        found_id
        USING ERRCODE = 'exclusion_violation';
    ELSEIF NOT FOUND THEN RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;

-- the actual constraint trigger
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER after_insert_constraint_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON debugging.my_data
    DEFERRABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION debugging.make_sure_ranges_not_overlapping();
```

And here is an INSERT which should fail, but which is instead allowed:

```sql
-- this succeeds, but it shouldn't
-- these ranges clearly overlap with one another, so why aren't they caught by the constraint trigger?
INSERT INTO debugging.my_data (id, range_min, range_max)
VALUES 
    (3, 60, 70),
    (4, 65, 75);
```

The most baffling thing to me is that I can actually copy the code from the trigger function into a SQL statement, fill in the `NEW.range_xxx` values with the same values I just inserted, and execute it after inserting the above data, and it will return the overlapping data just like it's supposed to. So for example, filling in the values for the second row inserted in that statement, I'd have this:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM debugging.my_data
WHERE int4range(65, 75, '[]') && int4range(range_min, range_max, '[]');
```

... and it returns

```
| id |
| 3  |
| 4  |
```

which is exactly what I SHOULD be getting - both ranges overlap with the range I supplied. So even though the logic I have for finding overlapping ranges works, for some reason, that logic is not being applied when I insert data into the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This example can (and should?) be handled by an end exclusion constraint. A trigger has issues with concurrent inserts and updates

Comment: This does not work because per here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null." and as the action(`AFTER INSERT`) implies the insert has already happened.  Remove `CONSTRAINT` from the trigger definition and change the action to `BEFORE INSERT`. Then `RETURN NEW` when you want thochanges to go through and `RETURN NULL` when you don't. It is spelled out at the link I included above.

Comment: @Frank An exclusion constraint would work in the `debugging.my_data` example, but I made that up for demonstration purposes - the actual business logic I need to enforce is too complicated for an exclusion constraint since it involves multiple tables. (cont., 1/2)

Comment: The logic involves multiple tables because the actual data I have are rulesets for an application, defined on different objects, which combine and override one another in a hierarchy - I need to make sure that once all the rulesets are combined, the final ruleset is still logically sound and unambiguous, so I use the trigger to reject any operation that would yield an invalid final ruleset. (2/2)

Comment: @Adrian triggers that fire `AFTER` can stop the row from being inserted/deleted/updated, you just need to raise an exception, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html) recommends: "Constraint triggers are expected to raise an exception when the constraints they implement are violated." Also, constraint triggers can be deferred just like regular constraints using `SET CONSTRAINTS ...`, whereas regular triggers can't, so the two aren't completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 95% correct, but unfortunately that missing 5% made it 100% wrong in your case.

It isn't working because your trigger function is marked as `STABLE`, when it should have been marked as `VOLATILE`. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) says:

> A `VOLATILE` function can do anything, including modifying the database. It can return different results on successive calls with the same arguments. The optimizer makes no assumptions about the behavior of such functions. A query using a volatile function will re-evaluate the function at every row where its value is needed.
>
> A `STABLE` function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments **for all rows within a single statement.** This category allows the optimizer to optimize multiple calls of the function to a single call. In particular, it is safe to use an expression containing such a function in an index scan condition. (Since an index scan will evaluate the comparison value only once, not once at each row, it is not valid to use a `VOLATILE` function in an index scan condition.)
>
> An `IMMUTABLE` function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments forever. This category allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a query calls it with constant arguments. For example, a query like `SELECT ... WHERE x = 2 + 2` can be simplified on sight to `SELECT ... WHERE x = 4`, because the function underlying the integer addition operator is marked `IMMUTABLE`.

The answer lies in a very careful reading of the documentation above. You saw "`VOLATILE` = modifying the database" and "`STABLE` = cannot modify the database", and since your trigger function doesn't modify the database, you mistakenly marked your trigger function as `STABLE`. However, whether your trigger function modifies the database or not wasn't the only condition you needed to pay attention to here: you failed to consider the fact that a `STABLE` function has to return the same results **for all rows within a single statement**.

Look at the code example you posted. You insert the following data:

```sql
INSERT INTO debugging.my_data (id, range_min, range_max)
VALUES 
    (3, 60, 70),
    (4, 65, 75);
```

This is a single statement. You expected that executing this statement would result in PostgreSQL saying "you can't insert range #4 because it overlaps with range #3". Or in other words, you expected that the first row you inserted would be considered when evaluating the constraint while attempting to insert the second row later in that same statement. But this is exactly what a `STABLE` function DOESN'T do - the `STABLE` function only has access to a single snapshot of the table's data as it was at the very start of the SQL command that is calling the function (Thank you @NickBarnes for pointing this out in the comments). To quote that same documentation page directly:

> For functions written in SQL or in any of the standard procedural languages, there is a second important property determined by the volatility category, namely the visibility of any data changes that have been made by the SQL command that is calling the function. A `VOLATILE` function will see such changes, a `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE` function will not. This behavior is implemented using the snapshotting behavior of MVCC (see Chapter 13): **`STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE` functions use a snapshot established as of the start of the calling query, whereas `VOLATILE` functions obtain a fresh snapshot at the start of each query they execute.**

So to reference rows inserted earlier within the same bulk `INSERT` statement, your trigger function must be `VOLATILE`. Note that, whether the trigger function is `STABLE`, `IMMUTABLE`, or `VOLATILE`, it will still be evaluated for each row as long as the trigger is a `ROW` trigger and not a `STATEMENT` trigger. It wasn't working as you intended when it was marked as `STABLE` because PostgreSQL was taking a single snapshot of the `my_data` table before inserting any rows and using that snapshot of the data each time the function was called. (Thanks again to @NickBarnes for pointing this out - I originally believed that PostgreSQL was only evaluating the trigger function once when it was `STABLE`, but that was inaccurate).

Moving on then to how to fix the problem. Luckily, you only have to do two simple things to make your constraint trigger work as intended.

First, mark the trigger function as `VOLATILE`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION debugging.make_sure_ranges_not_overlapping()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF -- *NOT* STABLE
AS $BODY$
    <rest of the function here>
$BODY$;
```

With this updated function definition, PostgreSQL will block you from inserting conflicting data. However, because the example code you posted is just an `EXCLUDE` constraint but written as a constraint trigger, and because constraint triggers, by definition, fire `AFTER INSERT`, this updated constraint trigger will actually block you from inserting *any* data into the table at all, because it will detect that the `NEW` row you just inserted overlaps with itself!

Therefore, to get around that bump in the road, the second thing you need to do is add a check in your trigger function's body so that it doesn't compare the row you just inserted to the row you just inserted. You can do this by either adding a clause like `WHERE id != NEW.id`, or more generically, `WHERE ROW(my_data.*) IS DISTINCT FROM NEW`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION debugging.make_sure_ranges_not_overlapping()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    found_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT id
        INTO found_id
    FROM debugging.my_data
    WHERE 
        id != NEW.id -- makes sure that you don't compare the row you just inserted to itself
        AND int4range(NEW.range_min, NEW.range_max, '[]') && int4range(range_min, range_max, '[]');
    IF FOUND THEN 
        RAISE 'Cannot insert range - it overlaps with range %',
        found_id
        USING ERRCODE = 'exclusion_violation';
    ELSEIF NOT FOUND THEN RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

To avoid this kind of issue in the future, a good rule of thumb would be that **if your constraint trigger references `NEW` or `OLD`, it needs to be marked as `VOLATILE`**.

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with marking this `STABLE`, exactly: `... a function containing only SELECT commands can safely be marked STABLE, even if it selects from tables that might be undergoing modifications by concurrent queries`. But the volatility marker also dictates which snapshot your function sees, which is the relevant detail here: `... there is a second important property determined by the volatility category, namely the visibility of any data changes that have been made by the SQL command that is calling the function`.

Comment: p.s. Note that the docs you quoted are specifically describing how volatility markers are treated by the _optimiser_, which is not involved in firing triggers. I think the unstated assumption there is that the "statement" in question is a query which is calling your function, and the "rows" are the rows in the result set. In practice, I believe this restriction is just to rule out things like `random()` and `clock_timestamp()`, which give different answers against the same database snapshot.

Comment: p.p.s. Your trigger is definitely firing twice, it just doesn't see any data in the table. You can confirm this by throwing in a `RAISE NOTICE` statement: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yb7utdaj

Comment: @NickB that online compiler is a fantastic resource, thanks for linking it! Also, how would you recommend I amend my original answer to be more correct? I asked+answered it myself because I wanted to help anyone else that might get stuck mistakenly thinking that their trigger isn't firing (like what I thought was happening), so I tried to explain things as accurately as possible, but evidently I got some of the details wrong. I actually noticed an error in the code "solution" I originally posted, so I fixed that too, but I want the other details of the answer to be accurate too.

Comment: Self-answers are encouraged, feel free to include anything you found useful. Though as I mentioned, I don't think the optimiser is involved here, so correct or not, a lot of this seems out of scope. [These docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-datachanges.html) might serve as a better starting point for describing the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: All that said, as @FrankHeikens mentioned above, there's a big problem with this solution. If two inserts run concurrently, both will see an empty table, both will commit successfully, and the constraint will be violated. There's no easy way around this, which is why exclusion constraints exist; failing that, you generally need some very expensive or very complicated locking protocols. There might be other ways to tackle this, but it's hard to say without details. In any case, I'd recommend setting up a reproducible test for this scenario, so you can be sure when you've actually solved it ;)

Comment: @NickBarnes you're right about triggers failing under concurrency - I tested it and it failed as you said! I'm split - on one hand, I'll be the primary user, and given how rarely I'll need to touch the tables, I could ignore the race condition and it'll realistically never occur. OTOH, I generally believe that a constraint that isn't 100% guaranteed by the database doesn't exist at all. I'll read up on locking, as I assume a constraint that must be enforced on the combined datasets of three tables is the kind that requires locking protocols - there'd be no "other ways to tackle", as you said?

Comment: Another possibility is to use the triggers to create a denormalised copy of the data in a fourth table, which you can then put an exclusion constraint on. But if you don't actually need to support concurrent writes in practice, then the simplest answer is probably to [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) all three tables before writing to any of them.